# How to generate different unimodal plots inside a multimodal plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn, gaussian

I'm plotting x and y value as a scatter plot, and getting a multimode peaks (three peaks):
[image: Multimodal plots]

I wanted to generate three unimodal curves in the plot like this:

[image: I want like this image]

Could you suggest a possible way generate lines inside a scatter plot. Thank you!

Comment: [GaussianMixture](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html)

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you for your response. I feel it should be an inversion of GaussianMixture. From the theory of Gaussian mixture, I understand it plots different unimodal plots into a single multimodal plot.

Comment: It is GaussianMixture l, that is trying to decompose the distribution into sum of several Gaussian distributions. See the link provided again.